# Can DDMS be used to debug processes running in hardware instead of an emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, analysis, ddms

The entire emulator runs in debug mode and therefore DDMS lists all the processes running inside the emulator.

However for a hardware device connected to DDMS, only the application being developed can be debugged and not the other processes. 
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: A little more info on what you're trying to achieve may be helpful. I.e. are you trying to debug an already present process external to your application?

Comment: I'm interested in monitoring and analysing the various applications running on my phone. Specifically their network, io usage, access patterns, system calls and functions invoked ie trace in general etc..